# Display custom post function ONLY if it has a value

Tags: custom-post-types

How do I get the following code to insert a link only if the custom function has a value?

```
<td><a href="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_review_link', true ) ); ?>"><div class="rating-<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_rating', true ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_rating', true ) ); ?></div></a></td>
```

Basically I'm trying to link a review score to a review but if a review hasn't been written I don't want a link to appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is primarily a **PHP** question, and not specific to WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
<?php $review_link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_review_link', true );
if ( ! empty( $review_link ) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_html( $review_link ); ?>">
        <div class="rating-<?php echo esc_html( $review_link ); ?>">
            <?php echo esc_html( $review_link ); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Chip Bennet, this is now working code.  Changed isset conditional check to ! empty.

Comment: `get_post_meta()` returns either an **empty array** (if `$single` is false) or an **empty string** (if `$single` is true). So, the return value will always be *set*. You'll need to check for an *empty string* in the conditional.

Comment: Thank you for the catch, Chip.  I meant to remove the true parameter.  I have updated the code in the answer.

Comment: But that `$single` is kind of important in this context, isn't it? ;)

Comment: +1 But: As in @ChipBennett  answer, `'' != get_post_meta()` should be used instead of a variable as the var is only used once. Avoids filling unnecessary stuff into memory.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the Codex entry for `get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), the function returns the specified value (if it exists), or else it returns an **empty string**.

So, you just need to check for an empty string:

```
if ( '' != get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_review_link', true ) ) {
    // Post meta value exists; do something
}
```

Comment: @JMa You can use `get_the_ID()` everywhere. Internally it calls `get_post()->post` and therefore fetches from the `global` and even updates on page cache so all future calls are fine as well.

Comment: Ah ok I was refering to the codex ("This tag must be within The Loop.") but I think you're right.